# Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, intellij-idea, configuration

I am trying to run spark unit tests with scala in intellij and it gives me the following error. It's funny because I thought that this error was caused by not using jdk 11 or 8, but in the configuration I'm using it.

Also, I can execute the class as such, the problem is only in the test. Any ideas?

- Error

[image: Stacktrace]

- Configuration

[image: Intellij Setup]

I have tried to change the jdk version to 11 too, and I have changed different parts of the test configuration, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Are you using any build tool such as sbt, mill, maven or any other one? have you tried execute the test from a terminal using the build tool? do you have a configuration file for the build tool that says which java version is targeting? is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so I just tried to print my java version before test starts

`print(System.getProperty("java.version"))`

and got 18.0.2. I think it is the problem but I don't why intelliJ is not using the configuration i have said.

I just changed the JDK versión in Project Setting menu and it worked